# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los pregijos <h:> y <p:> en JavaServerFaces?

Tags: java, jsf

Estuve investigando en esta pagina [documentacion de los tags JSF](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html) todas las etiquetas de JavaServerFaces para saber cual es su significado. Pero resulta que hay una que es **p:** que NO SÉ cual es su uso. Con el prefijo **h:** hay varias 
etiquetas como inputText, commandButton, dataTable, etc... Y el prefijo **p:** también las posee igualmente. ¿Cual es la diferencia?, el prefijo **p:** posee más contenido o es una nueva versión?

Además, en la documentacion de todos los tags con sus prefijos que les deje solo están presentes la **f:**, **h:** y **ui:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Comment: Hola, ¿Ya revisaste tu log? ¿Tienes XAMPP en ejecución y arrancas el tomcat al mismo tiempo? ¿El puerto 3306 esta siendo usado solo por tu aplicación? También puede ser que el driver MyQL no sea el adecuado.

Answer (score 0):

JSF es un framework basado en componentes y server side. Tienes componentes como botones, tablas, mensajes para mostrar en pantalla, etc. Las que tienen el prefijo h con el namespace "http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" son componentes propios de la implementación de JSF, es decir, son estándar del framework. Las que vienen del namespace "http://primefaces.org/ui" y en tu ejemplo tienen el prefijo p **no son estandar de JSF**, sino que vienen del proyecto [PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/getstarted.xhtml). ¿Que es Primefaces? Es un muy popular framework de componentes para JSF (ahora incluso tienen componentes para React y Angular). Extienden los que ya existen con mayores prestaciones e incluso agregan componentes adicionales. Para poder usarlos tienes que agregar los jar a tu proyecto. Espero haya aclarado tu duda.